# Prove $m$ is continuous from the left on $(a,b)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a bounded function on $[a, b]$. Show that the function defined by:

$$m(x) = \inf\{ f(ζ): ζ∈ [a, x)\}$$

is continuous from the left on $(a, b)$

I believe it would suffice to prove that $m$ is monotone decreasing, but I'm struggling trying to prove this on this set of functions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To prove $m$ is monotone decreasing, do as follows. Define

$$M_y=\{f(t):t\in[a,y)\}$$

Then $m(y)=\inf M_y$. Suppose that $x>y$. Then $M_y\subseteq M_x$. What does this tell you about $m(y)=\inf M_y$ and $m(x)=\inf M_x$?.

Comment: does this imply that m(y) $\leq$ m(x)

Comment: @user76215 $\{1,2\}\subseteq \{-1,1,2\}$. But $1\geq -1$. You want to prove it is **decreasing**, yes?

Comment: m(y)$\geq$ m(x)?

Comment: @user76215 Are you guessing?